# Top view of a Binary tree in python

Tags: python-3.x, tree, binary-tree

I am trying to solve the [top view of the binary tree](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/top-view-of-binary-tree/1#) problem on geeksforgeeks.com

> Given below is a binary tree. The task is to print the top view of binary tree. Top view of a binary tree is the set of nodes visible when the tree is viewed from the top. For the given below tree
>
> ```
>       1
>    /    \
>   2      3
>  / \    / \
> 4   5  6   7
> ```
>
> Top view will be: 4 2 1 3 7
>
> **Note:** Return nodes from **leftmost** node to **rightmost** node.

Can someone tell me where my code is wrong? It works for most of the cases that I tried for and fails for a case that is just simply too long to dry run.

```
class Solution:
  
    #Function to return a list of nodes visible from the top view 
    #from left to right in Binary Tree.

    def topView(self,root):
        left_ans = []
        def left_view(root,level) :
            if not root : return 
            if level > len(left_ans) : left_ans.append(root.data)
            left_view(root.left,level+1)
            left_view(root.right,level-1)
        
        right_ans = []
        def right_view(root,level) :
            if not root: return
            if level > len(right_ans) : right_ans.append(root.data)
            right_view(root.right,level+1)
            right_view(root.left,level-1)
        
        left_view(root,level = 1)
        right_view(root,level =1)
        
        return left_ans[::-1]+right_ans[1:]
```

Tree for which it fails:

```
               __________________23______________________
              /                                          \
          __17__                        _________________65__________________ 
         /      \                      /                                     \
      __9__      19            ______38_______                             __69__
     /     \    /  \          /               \                           /      \
    7      10  18  21       37       __________43__________              67      74
   / \       \    /  \     /        /                      \            /  \    /
  1   8      14  20  22  33       39                _______53_______   66  68  70
   \        /  \        /        /  \              /                \            \
    4      13  16   __29_      35   40           51                _62_          71 
   / \    /   /    /     \    /  \    \         /  \              /    \           \
  3   5  11  15  27      32  34  36   41      45   52          __58__  63          72 
 /     \   \    /  \    /               \    /  \             /      \   \           \
2       6  12  24  28  30               42  44   47          57      61  64          73
                 \       \                      /  \        /       /
                 26      31                    46  49      55      60 
                /                                 /  \    /  \    /
               25                                48  50  54  56  59
```

Expected output:

```
2 1 7 9 17 23 65 69 74 63 64
```

Output of my code (wrong):

```
2 1 7 9 17 23 65 69 74 72 73
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm assumes that the highest nodes are visited first, but this is not always the case. Here is a minimal example:

```
           7
          / \
         1   11
          \ /
           2 (10)
          / \
         9   6
        /   /
       8   5 
          /
         4
        /
       3
```

Note that the two branches that spring from the root, cross each other two levels down (the left child of 11 is 10, and the right child of 1 is 2). Since you visit the left subtree first, you'll register that 3 is visible from the top. When you later traverse the other path, this does not get updated.

One solution is to maintain at which depth a node was found. If later, at the same vertical offset (`level`) you find another candidate, you could compare the depths of these two nodes and decide which one is above the other.

A second issue is that the challenge mentions that the solution should *"Return nodes from leftmost node to rightmost node."*. This is a bit ambiguous statement, but it seems to mean that when two nodes are at the same height, and at the same vertical offset, precedence should be given to the node found via a left-first traversal. But in `right_view` you used the opposite order: just change the order of the recursive calls.

Here is your function updated with that notion of `depth` and the fixed recursive call-order:

```
def topView(self,root):
    left_ans = []
    left_depth = []
    def left_view(root,level,depth) :
        if not root:
            return 
        if level >= 0:
            if level >= len(left_ans): 
                left_ans.append(root.data)
                left_depth.append(depth)
            elif depth < left_depth[level]:
                left_ans[level] = root.data
                left_depth[level] = depth
        left_view(root.left,level+1,depth+1)
        left_view(root.right,level-1,depth+1)
    
    right_ans = []
    right_depth = []
    def right_view(root,level,depth):
        if not root:
            return
        if level >= 0:
            if level >= len(right_ans): 
                right_ans.append(root.data)
                right_depth.append(depth)
            elif depth < right_depth[level]:
                right_ans[level] = root.data
                right_depth[level] = depth
        right_view(root.left,level-1,depth+1)
        right_view(root.right,level+1,depth+1)
    
    left_view(root,0,0)
    right_view(root,0,0)

    return left_ans[::-1]+right_ans[1:]
```

Comment: I didn't understand your point about "Your algorithm assumes that the subtree at the right side cannot contain nodes that will appear in the top view of the left side". My algorithm is giving the correct answer for the example that you have given.

Comment: You're right; I misread your code. I have completely updated my answer, and provided a case where your code goes wrong. Please have a look.

Comment: I understood your point and yes my logic does assume that the highest node is visited first but I am still not unable to understand how that is not the case. Again for the above example, you gave, my algorithm gives the correct answer. I tested for both cases, (1) 6 is the right node of 2, and (2) 6 is the right node of 10.

Comment: Just tested your modified code on geeksforgeeks.com, your code fails for the same test case that my code is failing for. I think we are both missing something here.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the failed case (input/output). The site needs registration.

Comment: The issue is that the challenge mentions that the solution should *"Return nodes from leftmost node to rightmost node."*. In your function you did the opposite in `right_view`: I have updated that in my answer. Next time, could you make sure that all essential information is *in* the question and not behind a link?

Comment: Thank you for all the edits and clarification. I will keep your suggestions in mind.